# Does Heirlooms yield the XP bonus when the level range is exceeded?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am currently levelling a Death Knight with heirlooms, and some of the heirlooms that I have, are with the level 1-80 range (not upgraded to 1-85)

While playing the game, I went past level 80 and into 81.

**But does the heirlooms with the range of 1-80 still yield the 10% experience bonus?**

I know I could easily run a Heroic Pandaria dungeon to get the points needed to upgrade the Heirloom from 1-80 to 1-85, but since I did level with lower level Heirloom gear - I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No** - the level range on the heirloom items dictate the level range that the experience bonus is active. In addition to the statistics no longer scaling with your level, the experience bonus becomes inactive.

One popular trick to consider is that the level range is fully inclusive, so the experience bonus is still active until level 81 for level 1-80  heirlooms.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the level range is not inclusive.

I have personally tested it previously and plenty of people find the same:

http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/9280238411
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/1406593553
http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/999655-Question-about-Heirloom-XP-boost

Comment: Ditto on the non-inclusive.  But you can also get upgrades for all heirloom so it scales to lvl 85 now.